# How to force GPT partitions in kickstart for Oracle Linux 6

Tags: linux, gpt, mbr, kickstart

I want to configure OL6 kickstart to install a system that boots from BIOS but uses GPT partitioning instead of MBR, even for disks <2TB.

The relevant part of my kickstart file looks like this (`$ROOTDRIVE` has been correctly initialized):

```
%pre
parted -s $ROOTDRIVE mklabel gpt

bootloader --location=partition --append="elevator=deadline nomodeset inst.gpt" --driveorder=$ROOTDRIVE
part biosboot --fstype biosboot --size=1 --ondisk=$ROOTDRIVE
part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=500 --ondisk=$ROOTDRIVE
part pv.2 --size=1 --grow --ondisk=$ROOTDRIVE`
```

I have removed `clearpart --all --drives=$ROOTDRIVE` and `zerombr` as these supposedly wipe my `parted` GPT and reinstate MBR.

I believe the following in my conf should result in GPT:

- `parted mklabel gpt`
- `--location=partition` (not sure if I really need this?)
- `inst.gpt` (may be available in OL7 only?)
- `part biosboot`

Yet my resulting system still lists the primary drive as MBR (`msdos` label):

```
[root@localhost ~]$ parted -l
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 172GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
```

My question: is there any kickstart config I can use to ensure I end up with GPT disks rather than MBR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Newer versions of kickstart](https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) have a `--disklabel` flag for the `clearpart` option that can be set to `gpt`.  It appears this was added in Fedora21/RHEL7 so I am not sure if it is available in OL6.

There is an older flag to `clearpart`, `--initlabel`, that mentions it "initializes the disk label to the default for your architecture" and would use `gpt` for Itanium architecture.

If no usable options exist in your version of kickstart, you can configure the disks in the kickstart preinstall script.  You could use `parted` scripting, or whatever tool you use to configure your disks/RAID.